# alternate depending on whether their id is odd or even React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, alternate

I am using React for a web page. In a component, I have a div on the left and an image on the right.

I would like them to alternate depending on whether their id is odd or even.

```
function Item({ title, text, link, img,id }) {
  return (
    <div >
      <div>
        <h3>
          {title}
        </h3>
        <p>{text}</p>
        <a href={link}>
          text
        </a>
      </div>
      <img src={img} alt={title} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turn the div into a component and conditionally render them in the order you want:

```js
function Item(props) {
  return (
    props.id % 2 == 0 ? 
    <div >
      <Div {...props} />
      <img src={img} alt={title} />
    </div>
    :
    <div >
      <img src={img} alt={title} />
      <Div {...props} />
    </div>
  );
}


const Div = ({ title, text, link }) => (
  <div>
    <h3>
      {title}
    </h3>
    <p>{text}</p>
    <a href={link}>
      text
    </a>
  </div>
)
```

Comment: Accept the answer then. lol